# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION with array appending

Tags: swift, multithreading

I'm a new Swift coder on Xcode and I don't understand why this error happens.

The error :

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

It happens in XMLParser.swift in for-in loop with

```
Ss.append(Scene(title: e["name"].text!, imageStr: e["image"].text!, info: e["info"].text!, isEnabled: Bool(e["isEnabled"].text!)!, action: e["action"].text!, id: e.attributes["id"]!)!)
```

**My files**

**XMLParser.swift**

```
//
//  XMLParser.swift
//  Home
//
//  Created by Valentin Dusollier on 24/07/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Valentin Dusollier. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SwiftyXMLParser

class XMLParser {
    let data: String

    init?(data: String) {
        self.data = data

        let xml = try! XML.parse(data);

        //mainRoom
        var Ss: [Scene] = []

        for e in xml["home", "scenes", "scene"] {
            Ss.append(Scene(title: e["name"].text!, imageStr: e["image"].text!, info: e["info"].text!, isEnabled: Bool(e["isEnabled"].text!)!, action: e["action"].text!, id: e.attributes["id"]!)!)
        }

            //Home.mainRoom = Room(title: xml["home", "title"].text!, description: xml["home", "description"].text!, titleOfSection: "Scènes", backgroundStr: xml["home", "background"].text!, accessories: Ss);

    }

}

struct Home {
    static var mainRoom: Room = Room(title: "Connexion en cours", description: "", titleOfSection: "", backgroundStr: "", accessories: nil)!;
    static var rooms: [Room]? = nil;
}
```

**Scene.swift**

```
//
//  Scene.swift
//  Home
//
//  Created by Valentin Dusollier on 23/07/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Valentin Dusollier. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class Scene {

    var title: String
    var image: UIImage
    var info: String
    var isEnabled: Bool
    var action: String
    var id: String

    init?(title: String, imageStr: String, info: String, isEnabled: Bool, action: String, id: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = UIImage(named: imageStr)!
        self.info = info
        self.isEnabled = isEnabled
        self.action = action
        self.id = id
    }


}
```

**Room.swift**

```
//
//  Room.swift
//  Home
//
//  Created by Valentin Dusollier on 26/07/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Valentin Dusollier. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class Room {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var titleOfSection: String
    var accessories: Scene
    var background: UIImage

    init?(title: String, description: String, titleOfSection: String, backgroundStr: String, accessories: Scene?) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.titleOfSection = titleOfSection
        self.accessories = accessories!

        self.background = UIImage(named: "black-iphone")!;
        if backgroundStr != "" {
            let url = URL(string: backgroundStr)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

            if data != nil {
                self.background = UIImage(data: data!)!
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers ! :D

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint and check what is the actual error in the debugger. That error code means the debugger wasn't able to get the actual error, but using an exception breakpoint you should be able to catch it. Btw don't use force unwrapping of optionals unless you are 100% certain there will be a value in your optional by the time you force unwrap it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D I manage to catch the error.